# Getting date of datetimepicker returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT: I used the following line. However now it returns [object Object]

```
var currentDate = $( "#datetimepicker4" ).datetimepicker( "getDate" );
```

Im trying to get the date using datetimepicker, but I keep getting the following error

```
angular.js:11500 TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDate' of undefined
    at k.$scope.parseDate
```

Here is what the input looks like[image]

Here is where I initialize the datetimepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker();
            });
</script>
```

Here is the MainController where I attempt to retrieve the date and time.

```
var date = $('#datetimepicker4').data("datetimepicker").getDate();
    formatted = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + " " + date.getHours + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
  alert(formatted);
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try using `console.log` or similar to output `date` to make sure it's what you think it is?

Comment: I did but got undefined

Answer (score 0):

You missed the id selector

```
var date = $('#datetimepicker4').data("datetimepicker").getDate(),
--------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the problem which was to use the following line to get the date:

```
var date = $('#datetimepicker4').data("DateTimePicker").date()
```